# Twitter Bootstrap: Center Pills

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question is how you can center the pills?

I've tried to add center block around and also to change the `float:left` to `float:center` but nothing helps.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'float:center' oh if there was. So many developers would have so much time left in their lives. There are a few techniques to centre tabs if you google for it, but in the case of twitter-bs might need a fair bit of customising

Answer (score 84):

**This has gotten much simpler!** You just need to use the `text-center` class on the container, and apply `display:inline-block` to the `ul`. Just make sure you have a line break or paragraph tag separating the nav from any other elements within the container.

Done! 2 class additions, 1 line of CSS (don't modify the bootstrap css file!).

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <p>Copyright stuff</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
        <li><a href="#">Footer nav link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Footer nav link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center-pills { display: inline-block; }
```

**Edit 2015**: As Artur Beljajev has brought up, Flexbox support is now [common enough](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) that you may want to use that instead:

```
.center-pills {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This worked better for me than broox solution. With broox solution I was having a weird placement of the pills (one was always below). Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Any idea why adding this style would leave a space below (as if there's padding)?

Comment: @RachelS Which style are you using? Do you have a jsfiddle I can look at?

Comment: Note, I used Flexbox version and it didn't work when content was in mobile display port.  The original answer worked though.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for pointing that out. What did it do? What mobile view mode or device did you use?

Comment: @PrestonBadeer I was just using Chrome and emulating a mobile device, but basically it didn't have a 'block' display and was appearing to the right of the preceding `<div class="tab-content">`.  Maybe I should have placed the `<div/>` with above styles *inside* the tab-content div?

Comment: Make sure you're using the flex layout setting you want as well (row or column). Flexbox can be tricky!

Answer (score 54):

If you'd like variable width pills in a variable width container, I'd suggest using the `inline-block` display type and adding a class to the pill container.

Here is how I extended bootstrap for centering pills.

CSS:

```
.centered-pills { text-align:center; }
.centered-pills ul.nav-pills { display:inline-block; }
.centered-pills li { display:inline; }
.centered-pills a { float:left; }
* html .centered-pills ul.nav-pills { display:inline; } /* IE6 */
*+html .centered-pills ul.nav-pills { display:inline; } /* IE7 */
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12 centered-pills">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li><a href="#">derek</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">brooks</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">is</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">super</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">awesome</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added `ul.nav-pills` to the 3rd and 4th selectors in case you happen to have other lists insided of the centered-pills element like I did.
`.centered-pills ul.nav-pills li { display:inline; }
.centered-pills ul.nav-pills li a { float:left; }
`

Answer (score 25):

Or flexbox approach:

```css
.nav-pills {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution if target browsers can handle it. Thank you.

Comment: In my case I've got quite a few <li> elements so I've used this extra one
    `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Answer (score 6):

If you want the pills to be centered instead of left aligned you will need to change the css. You will need to specifiy a width and change the margin to be auto. 
For example:

```
.tabs, .pills {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: This is spot on, but I wouldn't recommend editing the CSS file. I would create my own CSS file to extend the Twitter Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Defining the width of 960px for Bootstrap helps you center something that otherwise won't center. Define the width and use offsets.

Comment: I would recommend prrstn's solution over this one. This fixes sizes which totally misses the point of using bootstrap in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer of @minaz works for a list with a known width, i'd propose a different solution which actually works even if you change the content of the list:

```css
.tabs, .pills {
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs li, .pills li {
  float: none;
}
```

Or in SCSS:

```css
.tabs, .pills {
  text-align: center;
  li { float: none; }
}
```

This will center the text inside the list, and resets the `float` property for the list items so they are affected by the `text-align` property.

Comment: this is grammatically incorrect. You cannot nest a css rule like this

Comment: You are correct, this was written in scss, which allows this kind of nesting. You'd have to pull the li part out and specify .tabs li and .pills li

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with **[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#horizontal-alignment)**
Use `justify-content-center` at `<ul>` nav

Example:

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="mt-5">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
      <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3 mx-2 px-2">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
      <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3 mx-2 px-2">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
      <div class="card text-white bg-danger mb-3 mx-2 px-2">
        <h1>Ni Hao</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 solution is very easy:

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/