# Unable to center align menu bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a website i.e. [website](http://www.punjaburduacademy.com/) I have used **Bootstrap 3** example layout to start and added my own css in another file. **But I am unable to center align the Navbar.** I have tried `col-md-10` & `col-md-offset`. Also tried adding `col-centered` css with `margin-left:auto;` & `margin-right:auto`. But unable to get it right.

Please help.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I have mentioned that navbar is not center aligned.

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939481/center-the-nav-in-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change HTML

```
<div style="width:100%; padding-left:0; padding-right:0;" class="container">
```

to

```
<div class="container">
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar-wrapper {
  background: #BECAD5;
}

.navbar {
  border: 0 none;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**PS:** I have seen so much inconsistency in your code. Please correct them. The above solution worked based on hacking the code. It could have been much simpler if your code was more organized.

[image: Centered Navbar]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As it is my first website design from scratch. So have inconsistency. I will try to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

use the bootstrap class

```
.center-block
```

to whatever you want to center align.

Comment: Which element did you use it on?  Can you post your code or a URL that works?  The link above is broken.