# How can I center my bootstrap navbar in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make it where all links within the navbar are centered and if I had more links they will automatically be centered as well.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you share more of your code ? because so many ways to center the content , if you share the code here , anyone can answer the right way

Comment: Most of my CSS for the navbar is just changing the color so it wouldn't really help lol

Comment: you need to share more codes ,else we can just answer based on our assumption.

Comment: @dreamhunter you are right

Comment: That's literally all my code, other than the html, body tags, etc.

Comment: Does this help ? http://css.co.in/centering-floating-divs.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center the nav in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939481/center-the-nav-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make `ul` `text-align:center;` & add `display: inline-block;` to `li` `a`

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you in understanding more.. http://www.bootply.com/CSI2KcCoEM

```css
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">Left 1</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">Left 2</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Center 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Center 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Center 3</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-right"><a href="#">Right 2</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-right"><a href="#">Right 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want you navbar to look like this??

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
          </header>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center your element setting giving `ul` the property of `display:inline-block;` and `margin:0 auto;` and then `text-align:center;` to its parent element

```
.navbar-nav{
  float:none !important;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:center"> <!--- added text-align center --->
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jbrh0n5d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `Class="Center-block"`

```
<div class="container-fluid" class="Center-block">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```