# Inline unordered list isn't centering properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a super simple site, [here](http://homegrowndevelopment.com/) that uses a sticky nav bar.  The list items are a couple of spots off to the left and I can't figure out why.  I've tinkered with all the margins and padding I can think of, but it won't budge.  I should also point out that I'm using Bootstrap.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse affix-top" data-spy="affix">
  <div class="navbar-inner" data-spy="affix-top">
    <div class="container">
 
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
 
      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service-top">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-arrow">Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!--/.nav-->
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse collapse pull-right-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
  </div><!--/.navbar-inner-->
</div><!--/#nav /.navbar navbar-inverse-->
</div><!--/#nav-wrapper-->
```

And here is my CSS that relates to my navigation:

```
.navbar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding:0;
    z-index:999;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background: #390 url(../img/green-bg.png) repeat;
    border:none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0; 
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar .nav, .navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:0 2em;
    margin:0;
}
.navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar-inner ul.nav li {
    text-align: center;
}
    .navbar .nav > li a{
    color:white; 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    text-shadow:none; 
    font-size:1.5em; 
    font-family: marvel, serif; 
    padding:.5em 1em; 
    margin:.5em 1em;
}
.navbar .nav > .active a:hover, .navbar .nav > li a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active a {
    color:white; 
    background: #390 url(../img/green-bg.png) repeat;
    text-shadow:none; 
    font-size:1.5em; 
    font-family: marvel, serif; 
    padding:.5em 1em; 
    margin:.5em 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000;
}
.navbar .nav > li {
    padding:1em;
    margin:0;
}
#nav.affix, #nav.affix-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
#nav {
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

I know it's a minor detail, but I've been trying to fix it for days now and can't figure out why it's being a pain.

Thanks for your help,

Brian

Comment: what list items are you talking about? please be more specific ...

Comment: there's only 1 set of list items...

Answer (score 2):

You have a right margin of 10px on the `.navbar .nav`(bootstrap.min.css:9) which pushes it a bit to the left.

Change this:

```
.navbar .nav {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  left:0;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  position:relative;
}
```

to this:

```
.navbar .nav {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The good news, is here is how to center the list items:

Add a class called ".center" like so:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top center">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
         ....
      </div>
 </div>
```

And then use this CSS:

```
.center.navbar .nav,
.center.navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
}

.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;
}
```

To realign the drop down menus, use this:

```
.center .dropdown-menu {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[This was taken from a previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568103/modify-twitter-bootstrap-navbar)

Now, the bad news, is that solution also centers the menu items on the mobile-menu drop down for tablet and mobile viewports.   I literally just posted a question on there ten minutes ago here:

[How to Override/Undo CSS Class Attributes for Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861175/how-to-override-undo-css-class-attributes-for-twitter-bootstrap/14861260#14861260)

If you find a solution, please let me know because we are both asking the same question!