# Bootstrap 3.0 Navbar Center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im in the middle of migrating my project form Bootstrap 2.3.2 to Bootstrap 3.

I am unable to center the navbar links as I was able to before. I used this method previously: [Center bootstrap's brand and list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305221/center-bootstraps-brand-and-list-items) but is not working for my new navbar.

The below link is a jsfiddle direclty using one of bootstraps examples (with the sticky footer and navbar)

Can someone please help me center these links?

http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services & Promos</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .navbar-default > .container { text-align: center }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Good info can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024463/bootstrap-3-how-do-i-place-the-brand-in-the-center-of-the-navbar

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [site](http://bootply.com/new), Paste your bootstrap 2.3.2 code in here, and click button showing `2.x>3`.

This will migrate your code automatically to 3.0.

`OR`

Refer [this](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide/#migration), to get bootstrap documentation for migration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I've tried this, but the CSS doesnt change. And using the same HTML over, the classes for the nav change and are not centered. Am I missing something in my code in specifying the nav?