# bootstrap 3 - how do I place the brand in the center of the navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.  I would like a navbar with only the brand in it.  No other links or anything else. And I want the brand to be in the center.  How can I accomplish this?  The following css doesn't work:

```
.navbar-brand {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**css**:

```
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand {float:none;}
```

**html**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This messes with the collapsed navigation menu for me

Comment: Having a width of 100% causes the header to overlap the collapsed navigation menu button making it unclickable.  Having a narrower and centred navbar-header should stop the overlap leaving the button clickable.

Comment: If using LESS, you can specify `@navbar-padding-vertical` instead of `padding: 15px;`.

Comment: According to the question they dont need navbar-header since they don't have any other links in it. However, for others who do want links either increase the z-index of navbar-toggle or consider this apporach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34150526/3123861

Answer (score 24):

Use these classes: `navbar-brand mx-auto`

All other solutions overcomplicate the matter.

Comment: `mx-auto` is Bootstrap 4. OP is using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: This is the best one!

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use `nav-justified`..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
    float:none;
}
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/98333)

[Alternate example](http://www.codeply.com/go/dv4rPK0Xws)

Comment: There seems to be a problem when using a mobile?

Answer (score 6):

**If you have no other links, then there is no use for navbar-header....**

*HTML:*

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
     <a class="navbar-brand text-center center-block" href="#">Navbar Brand</a>
  .....
</nav>
```

*CSS:*

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: none;
}
```

**However, if you do want other links here's a very effective approach that allows that:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/34149840/3123861

Answer (score 1):

To fix the overlap, you only need modify the .navbar-toggle in your own css styles

something like this, it works for me:

```
.navbar-toggle{
z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used two classes to achieve this and maintain responsiveness `navbar-brand-left` and `navbar-brand-center`. Keep in mind it utilises Sass / Less Bootstrap for line height, otherwise specify a hardcode px / rem height.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand-left visible-xs visible-sm">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Brand</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Start now</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand-left {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: @navbar-height;
}

.navbar-brand-center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: @navbar-height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create this class and add it to your element to be centered.

```
.navbar-center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap, simply use `mx-auto` class along with `navbar-brand`.