# Wrap a list to new line in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Bootstrap navbar, I have a logo in the header and then an inline list. On large screens, the logo and list are on the same line. On smaller screens, I want the logo centered on the first line and the list to center on a second line. But, the list keeps going to vertical stacked instead of remaining inline. How can I prevent the inline list from going vertical as the screen shrinks?

Here is a jsfiddle of my current navbar: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6936/

I need the links on the right to get closer and closer to the logo as the screen shrinks. Then, when there's no more room, I need those links centered on a new line below the logo, which should be centered on the first line.

Desired effect on small screens: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08LN9pHRwLuSkRvV3YwYVk5aWs/view?usp=sharing

html:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x75" class="img-responsive navlogo" alt="logo here"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul class="list-inline nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-list">
          <li><a href="#" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="color: black; font-weight: bold">Policies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="background-color: #9e1d2a; color: white">For Users</a></li>
          <li style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 15px"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav-search-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="nav-search-collapse">
      <ul class="list-inline navbar-list-form">
        <li><form class="navbar-form" role="form" method="get" action="#">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="Search" placeholder="Search Data" class="form-control" name="q">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form></li>
        <li><form class="navbar-form" role="form" method="get" action="#">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">wwww.</span>
            <input type="Search" class="form-control" name="w_searched">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <span>Search</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.navbar-list {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-list li{
    font-size: 16px;
}

#nav-search-collapse {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.navbar-list-form {
 display:inline-block;
 padding: 0;
}


@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .navbar-header{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    } 
    .navbar-links {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to your CSS will give you what you are looking for (you are required to define minimum width up-till which all links appear on same newline, it's your decision)

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 0px) {
    .navbar-links {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav>li {
        display: inline;
    }
    .nav>li>a {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user501254/mxczg3vz/1/)

Comment: Thank you, @ashesh! Both this and @odedta's answer work- this one, though, is easier for me to now style/align the links so they are centered. I will "accept" it. Thank you both so much!!

Comment: one more thing @ashesh or @odedta: I can't get the logo to center itself on the top line...? I've tried using `margin: auto;` and `text-align: center;` but no luck

Comment: `.navbar-header {
  text-align: -webkit-center; }` or a much better way to do it can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20029582/2534513)

Comment: glad that I could help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6940/](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6938/)

I have added this code:

```
.navbar-logo, .navbar-links {
    display: inline;
    width: initial !important;
}
```

If you have any questions about the modifications let me know.

Comment: By the way, this media query `@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1000px)` can be skimmed down to `@media (max-width: 1000px)`

Comment: Thank you- that is getting closer but I'm trying to get the links to remain on one line rather than stacking one on top of the other. I'll attach a screenshot of the desired effect...

Comment: Then use display: inline for the list items as well.