# Centering links (within li's) in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568103/modify-twitter-bootstrap-navbar) which *almost* solves my problem, however, I need the `<ul class="nav">` to be centered between the entire navbar and not just the elements adjacent to it (`<a class="brand">` and `<p class="navbar-text pull-right">` in my case).

Important: I [customized](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html) my navbar to be `96px` instead of the default `40px`, and I want the `<ul class="nav">` to appear centered and "underneath" the other elements as it will have its own background-color etc.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top center">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="/home"><img src="http://jayeshcp.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/twitter-bootstrap.jpg" style="width:400px;height:60px;" /></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                    <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                </p>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the extra `center` class that I added - that is from the solution that I linked to. It looks like this:

```
.center.navbar .nav,
.center.navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
}

.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;
}

.center .dropdown-menu {
    text-align: left;
}
```

How do I center the `ul` and give it padding above without breaking everything else in Bootstrap? Would offer more than bounty if there was another currency!

**edit:** jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekn_/C7LWm/102/) (I pasted the whole minified css file (with the customized navbar height) instead of referencing it, sorry. Underneath it are the other customizations.)

Comment: Make a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Might take me a moment to make it accurate. Will edit my post soon with it unless I get an answer before I'm done.

Comment: Sort of like : http://jsfiddle.net/8BTrx/ ?

Comment: Yeah except with bigger navbar and a silly logo. I updated my post with a jsfiddle link. The whole idea is for the links to sit _underneath_ the other stuff, and always centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p.navbar-text
{
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
}
.navbar .nav
{
    display:block !important;
    float: right !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C7LWm/103/

Here's the solution for placing it underneath instead of below:

```
.navbar .nav
{
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color:yellow;
}
p.navbar-text
{
   width: 440px;
   text-align:right;
   position:relative;
   z-index:2
}
.navbar .brand 
{ 
   position: relative; 
   z-index:2; 
   padding: 0; 
   width: 30%;
   height: 60px;
   background-image: url('http://placehold.it/400x60&text=Your Logo Here');
   background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;
   margin: 18px 0;
   background-position: center left
}
.navbar .brand img
{
   display:none;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C7LWm/109/

Comment: This doesn't work because it increases the height of the navbar. The <ul> must be positioned absolute I would think. (The logo image is just for demo, I'll be positioning it a bit higher)

Comment: This would be underneath: http://jsfiddle.net/C7LWm/105/ and I applied a yellow background to the ul so you can see it's size/width.

Comment: That looks like the solution :) I just added some 'padding-top' to '.navbar .nav'. I'm gonna carry on testing it. Should I used padding or margin? They both seem to do the same thing in this context.

Comment: They should be similar in effect.  Here's one that I changed out the logo from placeholder.it, move it to a style and hide the img, and cause to it to scale some to make a bit more room for smaller screens: http://jsfiddle.net/C7LWm/109/

Comment: That's even better! Is there any way to make the '.jcenter.navbar .nav, .jcenter.navbar .nav > li' float left instead of none (ie. float the nav links left) for when responsive kicks in for smaller screens? If that's overkill and will cause other issues I can live with it staying in the center.

Comment: 'margin-top' is what I used because I needed to give the ul a background-color