# how to write new navbar class in bootstrap-theme.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added div class for my menus and i like to display all in a same line.

This is my div class.

```
  <div class="navbar-inner">
```

I have added some codes in my bootstrap-theme.css.

```
  .navbar-inner
   {
    display: inline;
   }
```

I'm using bootstrap in yii framework.
but this code is not working.Whether i need to add any codes or not?
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568103/modify-twitter-bootstrap-navbar?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one "float:none;display:inline-block;". it will help your.