# How to center Bootstrap navigation items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out how to center the navigation items. I can place them either to the left or right but not center. Is there a simple work around?

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Mobile navigation button --> 
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
      </button>
      <!-- Navigation items -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">OUR PRODUCTS</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">OUR TEAM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried a few things but they're a little sloppy and caused some issues with mobile version. I'm looking for something a little more proper.

Comment: My attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/miparnisari/vgdg30Lp/

Comment: @UnknownOctopus It's all bootstrap. I tried a few things with some custom css that didn't work.

Comment: This thread should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568103/modify-twitter-bootstrap-navbar

Comment: here you go, https://jsfiddle.net/kog04xsg/1/

Comment: @Shehary this didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @b4n4n4 u wana put the dropdown nav links in center or the nav icon in center?

Comment: @Shehary I'd like the keep the mobile version of the navigation the same, everything to the right. I want the desktop version of the navigation to be centered though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you forgot to add or edit.

On your Bootstrap.css go find this class and edit on `text-align:center`. This will make your text navbar be centerized.

```
.navbar.navbar-collapse{

text-align: center;

}
```

If you still don't get it. You can take a look my example that i do on Bootply.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">OUR PRODUCTS</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">OUR TEAM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>

 </div>
```

CSS

```
   @media (min-width: 620px) {
        .navbar .navbar-nav {
            display: inline-block;
            float: none;
        }

        .navbar .navbar-collapse {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/uf8KKjehkk#)

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `<ul class="nav nav-justified"`... for the menu container.

2) Look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/davidcochran/pen/rcHae) source:

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li
{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

3) Read the answer [right there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18778769/5208760)

There are three different ways to do something like You want, choose one.

You could easily find your answer, please try to do this alone next time, bro.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some custom CSS via flexbox.

```
.nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    float: none; // overwrites Bootstrap's float value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li
{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav > li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```