# Center Pills in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

new to Bootstrap, following this question almost exactly, and can't seem to make my pills/tabs center?

```
</head> <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<html>
```

```
.nav-tabs > li, .nav-pills > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
     zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
}

.nav-pills {
    text-align:center;
}
```

I have the CSS in a file called style.css, and I am importing as such

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css">
```

Both files are within the bootstrap folder, so not really sure what's going on

Comment: http://jsbin.com/axizic/1 looks OK to me. You sure you don't have other styles conflicting with it?

Comment: Oh shoot, it was conflicting with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">`, what is the difference between that and `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css">`? The first one when commented out fixes the issue, the second works regardless?

Comment: both should work. the order in which you include styles matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap: Center Pills](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165423/twitter-bootstrap-center-pills)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the .nav-pills css classes defined by bootstrap (as you are already doing). You should update the margin and the specify a width for the element.

```
.nav-pills {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use With Attribute, this approach is more elegant, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421966/how-do-i-center-the-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with **Bootstrap 5** :

- set `d-inline-block` for the `ul`
- set `d-inline` for `li` and `a`
- then insert all that in a container with `text-center`

---

```
<nav class="container text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills d-inline-block">
        <li class="nav-item d-inline">
            <a class="nav-link d-inline active" href="#">nav 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-inline">
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">nav 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-inline">
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">nav 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```