# Bootstrap - Center Tabs in Container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this page, I have several tabs. At this time, the tabs are left-aligned across the top. You can see yourself in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/03cnW7CnUY). I'm trying to figure out how to make the tabs appear in the center of the tab strip. As of right now, it looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| Tab 1 | Tab 2 |
+       +-------+--------------------------------------------------+
| content                                                          |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
                          +-------+-------+
                          | Tab 1 | Tab 2 |
+-------------------------+       +--------------------------------+
| content                                                          |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried using the text-center class without success. I know the `ul` is a block-level element so it fills the width of its container. For that reason, I tried setting `float:left` on the ul. But that didn't work either. Once again, the Bootply is [here](http://www.bootply.com/03cnW7CnUY). The code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#first" aria-controls="first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">First Tab</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#second" aria-controls="second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Second Tab</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="first">
                    <h2>First Tab</h2>
                </div>

                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="second">
                    <h2>Second Tab</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to get the tabs to center.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/czd60374/1/

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422253/5168300

copying this answer

> nav-tabs list items are automatically floated to the left by the bootstrap so you have to reset that and instead display them as inline-block, and to center menu items we have to add the attribute of text-align:center to the container, like so:

CSS

`.nav-tabs > li, .nav-pills > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
     zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
}`

`.nav-tabs, .nav-pills {
    text-align:center;
}`

here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8HGz/2/

Edit: patched version that works in IE7+ provided by user @My Head Hurts down in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the css for `ul.nav-tabs` and the `li`, like so:

```
ul.nav-tabs {
  text-align: center;
}
ul.nav-tabs li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/pwyumb3k/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

HTML:

```
   <ul class=" ul-center" role="tablist">
           <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>    </li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>    </li>  
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.ul-center{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
}
.ul-center li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin:0;
}
```

LIVE DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/czd60374/1/