# Make Social Media Buttons Horizontal on Bootstrap mobile dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about getting the social media buttons to align next to each other -- that is, horizontally rather than vertically -- in the mobile mode on the drop down menu?

The icons are within a standard bootstrap nav bar, aligned to the right side of the bar.

Whenever someone clicks on the mobile drop down menu it currently lists these icons vertically. I want them horizontal.

Here is my code for the menu div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li class="active"></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Welcome </a> </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://broadmarkpartners.com">Broadmark Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://broadmark.io/blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" >
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            </li>
                            <li>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"  class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            </a>
            </li>
                            <li>
            <a href="https://github.com/broadmarkio" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-github">
                <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
            </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="text-muted">&nbsp;</h3>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you just need to apply the `nav-pills`-class to the list like so.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pills">
```

see your sample working here: http://www.bootply.com/pm5SsVZrOi

Comment: How can I center the social media buttons in mobile view, and not just align the horizontaly to the left?

Comment: have a look at the 3rd answer to this question on  SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165423/twitter-bootstrap-center-pills maybe this does what you need